# Spark: optimized join with ElasticSearch index

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-spark

So I'm learning to take data from ElasticSearch throught Apache Spark.
Let's say I've connected to ElasticSearch that has 'users' index.

```
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
usersES=sqlContext.read.format('org.elasticsearch.spark.sql').option('es.nodes','mynode').load('users/user')
```

explain(usersES) shows me this:

> == Physical Plan ==
>
> Scan ElasticsearchRelation(Map(es.nodes -> mynode,
>   es.resource ->
>   users/user),org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext@6c78e806,None)[about#145,activities#146,bdate#147,
>   uid#148]

When I use filter:

```
usersES.filter(usersES.uid==1566324).explain()
```

> == Physical Plan == Filter (uid#203L = 1566324)
>   +- Scan ElasticsearchRelation(Map(es.nodes -> mynode, es.resource ->
>   users/user),org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext@6c78e806,None)[about#145,activities#146,bdate#147,uid#148]
>   **PushedFilters: [EqualTo(uid,1566324)]**

As you see, Spark elegantly pushes the filter to ElasticSearch, making the index search fast and comfortable.

But when I try joining usersES with another dataframe, I get the same issue all the time:
**Spark scans through the whole ElasticSearch index, not pushing any filters I give it.**
For example:

```
a = sc.parallelize([1566324,1566329]).map(Row('id')).toDF()
a.join(usersES, usersES.uid==a.id).explain()
```

shows:

> SortMergeJoin [id#210L], [uid#203L] :- Sort [id#210L ASC], false, 0 : 
>   +- TungstenExchange hashpartitioning(id#210L,200), None :     +- ConvertToUnsafe :        +- Scan ExistingRDD[id#210L] 
>   +- Sort [uid#203L ASC], false, 0    +- TungstenExchange hashpartitioning(uid#203L,200), None
>         +- ConvertToUnsafe
>            +- Scan ElasticsearchRelation(Map(es.nodes -> mynode, es.resource ->
>   users/user),org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext@6c78e806,None)[about#145,activities#146,bdate#147,uid#148]

Please, tell me, is that possible to push filter inside Elasticsearch inside the join?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an expected behavior, yes elaticsearch-hadoop connector supports pushdown predicate but there is no push when you join.

This is because the join operation does not know anything about how the keys are partitioned in your dataframes.

By default, this operation will hash all the keys of both dataframes, sending all the elements with the same key hash across the network to the same machine, and then join together the elements with the same key on that machine.

And that's why you get that execution plan without the predicate being pushed down.

**EDIT :** It seems like the connector supports since the version 2.1 the ***IN*** clause. You ought using that if your DataFrame a isn't big.

- Ref 1. https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop/issues/556
- Ref 2. https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop/commit/bbe6154226f4700a9ac23c3d611b6c313bfbaf59

Comment: Thanks! Seems like this is the only way, although not fitting my needs (thousands of records in df to py inside the IN)

Comment: Well than the only way is to use spark to join instead of the In clause or you can even use a broadcast variable.

Comment: Can you please at least accept the answer to close the issue ?

Comment: I have a similar need. I think I can fit one of the dataframes into a broadcast var. If that is the case (a broadcast-hash-join) will Spark be using Elastic's indexes?

Comment: @Avision what do you mean by « spark using elastic’s indexes » ?

Comment: @eliasah I mean that if one of the DFs that I wish to join fits into memory then the key that I join on can be searched for on the larger DB using ElasticSearch index. In other words it can be mapped to something similar to the IN operation. So my question is, does this happen, or does Spark perform a regular join as if the underlying source has no index?

Comment: Joins can’t happen on elasticsearch. The in predicate is just pushed to filter when needs to be pulled from one index to spark which is later joined on spark.

Comment: what if the join is between two ES indexes? will it push down?

Comment: @user1870400 not that I'm aware of... Joins between ES indices doesn't exist in ES alone, so the same rule apply.

Comment: @eliasah ok But what if I have `select * from index1 join index2  on index1.col1 = index2.col1 where index1.col2 = "Foo" AND index2.col2 = "Bar"`. What happens now? Does it push down the filters at least and select a join type based on the dataset(like sortmerge or broadcast etc) and do it in memory? or is it just dumb like bring everything in memory and then apply filter also in memory?

Comment: @user1870400 If you haven't precised the filters when loading data, it will bring everything to memory from each index

Comment: @eliasah "If you haven't precised the filters" ? what does this mean? Assume all the data is in ES cluster across multiple indexes. And I issued the following query. `select * from index1 join index2 on index1.col1 = index2.col1 where index1.col2 = "Foo" AND index2.col2 = "Bar"` What happens?

Comment: @user1870400 This means that it will pull all the data first and then perform the join. According to the main developer on the project, the 'join' conditions won't be parsed. How are you reading those data ?

Comment: @eliasah will it pick a particular join type at very least? or does it always use SortMergeJoin? I use Multiple indexes setting for `es.resource`  to get the dataframe df and then issue a join query using `df.sql("select * from index1 join index2 on index1.col1 = index2.col1 where index1.col2 = "Foo" AND index2.col2 = "Bar"")`